# Convert '1|2|India' this pipe delimited String set as column

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, mysql-workbench

i have table with three column (State_id,Country_id,state_name).and i have pipe delimited String like this (1|2|ABC).

now What i want to do whenever i hit trigger at that time whatever this pipe delimited String is Convert into as column name like

```
Insert INTO tablename values (1,2,ABC);
```

each and every time i have different pipe delimited String with different column.maybe its 4 or more then.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);
simple_loop: LOOP
    SET a=a+1; 
    SET str=SPLIT_STR(new.remarks,"|",a); 
        IF str='' THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop; 
        END IF;
insert into new.tablename values (str);
END LOOP simple_loop;
```

END

i have made SPLIT_STR which is split the value on by one

```
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
   LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
   delim, '')
```

i have tried like this.but it's does not work.

Comment: Is this for Oracle or MySQL? From the syntax you have tried it looks like MySQL, in which case the Oracle tag needs to go to avoid confusion.

Comment: this is mysql .

Comment: Ah, OK. I only know Oracle.

Comment: What does not work the split_str function, syntax error, insert into new.tablename?

Comment: This kind of problem is vaguely symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 0):

split your string using **substring_index** from delimiter position like below:

```
 Insert INTO tablename
 select substring_index('1|2|ABC','|',1),
        substring_index(substring_index('1|2|ABC','|',2),'|',-1),
        substring_index('1|2|ABC','|',-1);
```

Comment: What if every time i have distinct pipe delimited String ? how do i make this Query Dynamic for distinct number of row

Comment: you can use find_in_set function for such like condtion and on the basis of count you can generate dynamic query

Comment: can you please tell what would be a code . it will help me alot